Maven assembly plugin with multi-module spring-boot
I've this multi module spring-boot project
-- module_1
        -- pom.xml
-- module_2
        -- pom.xml
-- pom.xml

module 2 has a dependency on module 1
with mvn package the jar file is created into module_2/target and contains this structure:
org/
module-info.class
META-INF/
BOOT-INF/

I want to create the jar file in parent/target and not in module_2/target
I tried with assembly plugin in module_2 pom.xml:
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <outputDirectory>../target</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

and the jar file is correctly created in parent's target but contains all folders and not the spring-boot structure

Simply creating the jar file in the root location does not work nor does not really make sense... furthermore for a spring boot project use the spring-boot-maven-plugin instead of the maven-assembly-plugin

thanks @khmarbaise using  spring-boot-maven-plugin and ../target solves my problem

Setting output directory to a higher level why?

@khmarbaise an external script wants that folder
